# How do I configure a Kernel test?

Tags: 8, testing

Currently I am able to run the Unit test from the below command

```
C:\Acquia_dev_desktop\LocalInstance\drupal_new_lab\vendor\bin>phpunit -c 
 ../../core/phpunit.xml.dist ../../modules/custom/lse_demo/tests/src/Unit

PHPUnit 6.5.0 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
......                                                              6 / 6 
(100%)
Time: 10.62 seconds, Memory: 6.00MB
OK (6 tests, 12 assertions)
```

But When I tried to do the same with Kernel test I get below error

```
C:\Acquia_dev_desktop\LocalInstance\drupal_new_lab\vendor\bin>phpunit -c ../../core/phpunit.xml.dist ../../modules/custom/lse_demo/tests/src/Kernel
PHPUnit 6.5.0 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

EEEEEE                                                              6 / 6 (100%)

Time: 11.43 seconds, Memory: 6.00MB

There were 6 errors:

1) Drupal\Tests\lse_demo\Kernel\DefaultControllerKernelTest::testDefaultController with data set #0 ('work', 'User', 'Welcome User to Work')
PHPUnit\Framework\Exception: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PHPUnit\Framework\Exception: Could not read "../../core/phpunit.xml.dist".

  thrown in C:\Acquia_dev_desktop\LocalInstance\drupal_new_lab\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Util\Configuration.php on line 189

Fatal error: Uncaught PHPUnit\Framework\Exception: Could not read "../../core/phpunit.xml.dist".

  thrown in C:\Acquia_dev_desktop\LocalInstance\drupal_new_lab\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Util\Configuration.php on line 189

PHPUnit\Framework\Exception: Could not read "../../core/phpunit.xml.dist". in C:\Acquia_dev_desktop\LocalInstance\drupal_new_lab\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Util\Configuration.php on line 189
```

Comment: I usually see it recommended to run the tests from the root directory. Try `C:\Acquia_dev_desktop\LocalInstance\drupal_new_lab\>./vendor/bin/phpunit -c core/phpunit.xml.dist modules/custom/lse_demo/tests/src/Kernel`

Comment: I copied phpunit.xml.dist to the root folder with the below configuration.


 `<env name="SIMPLETEST_BASE_URL" value="http://drupaleightsix.dd:8083/"/>
 
 <env name="SIMPLETEST_DB" value="mysql://drupaluser@localhost/drupaleightsix"/>`

 
And ran the below command, Now I am getting below error

 `G:\Acquia dev desktop\LocalInstance\drupal_eight_six>vendor\bin\phpunit  modules/custom/lse_demo/tests/src/Kernel

 PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.`

Could you please help me to configure phpunit.xml.dist ?

Comment: You probably need a password in your connection URL `mysql://username:password@localhost/databasename#table_prefix`

Comment: Database does not have a password.

Comment: @Ashi usually `machine actively refused it` means that the service is either not running or runs on different port or network interface. Check that you have MySQL running on 127.0.0.1 and uses 3306 port (default).

Comment: Thank you @d70rr3s Changing the MYSQl port resolved my issue

Answer (score 0):

Ensure  your connection string in the phpunit.php.dist is correct. The correct format is:

```
mysql://username:password@localhost/databasename#table_prefix
```

Answer (score -1):

example

put phpunit.xml.dist to root directory

path inside the above file name is

./core/tests/TestSuites/UnitTestSuite.php
    
    
      ./core/tests/TestSuites/KernelTestSuite.php
    
   
      ./core/tests/TestSuites/FunctionalTestSuite.php

./vendor/bin/phpunit --no-coverage UnitTest ./modules/custom/helloworld/tests/src/Unit/helloWorldTest.php

try the same for kernelTest

my test file starts

=====================

namespace Drupal\Tests\helloworld\Unit;

use Drupal\Tests\UnitTestCase;
use Drupal\helloworld\Helloworld;